# Thinkpad T410i SSD M.2

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

I would like to upgrade my Thinkpad T410i with SSD M.2 disk.
The notebook has miniPCIE port (WWAN module).
Can I put M.2 SSD disk to miniPCIE port?

Answer (score 0):

M2 is NGFF, which is incompatible with mPCIe. And anyway, those in T410i are mPCIe only, not even mSATA.

You may have some luck if you buy mSATA SSD with integrated SATA controller, but those are rare and expensive. But M.2 won't work.